# IoT Smart home recommendation - controlling lights

Tags: raspberry-pi, smart-device

Ok so I am going to be building a smart home using a small Raspberry possibly but I needed some recommendations! I hope this is the right place to post. But basically here is what i was thinking:

Possibly use a Relay Switch to control the lights in my room, but use a transmitter and receiver to make it go on and off using the Raspberry Pi. But i am not sure exactly HOW to do it. What would the layout be or the schematics?

Thank you everyone for helping!

Comment: This is a very broad question. Let's try to narrow it down a bit. Have you decided on which protocol you want to utilize for controlling the lights?

Comment: @Andy sorry extremely new to this, just getting started. Basically I just need to connect the Pi to my receiver using the GPIO pins, then the transmitter inside of the wall / light switch are will be controlling a relay switch (or something else, that controls the on and off of the power)

Comment: I understand, but those transmitters utilize different protocols. Which one you want the entire system to use will determine what hardware you can utilize as several are not compatible with one another. Do you know what software you want to use yet? That may help narrow down responses too. For a **very** brief summary of protocols, this [link](http://home-automation-systems-review.toptenreviews.com/a-guide-to-home-automation-protocols.html) has a quick run down. I suggest a more detailed Googling too.

Comment: @Andy Well, I am not sure which protocal it uses, I just ordered them. Here is a link: http://www.ebay.ca/itm/351552385074?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

Comment: @Andy I am trying to make it run off the GPIO pins but using Python and coding it from that, if this then that with if statements. It will use a voice API to translate natural human language input from a microphone or over HTTP (i'll take care of this later) and use that to control the transmitter based on that. Is that enough information? I hope I am not missing anything. Thank you again :) Again extremely new and have NO IDEA what i am doing

Comment: It sounds like you're asking what the schematics for a system would be. If that's the case, I'm afraid that's not on-topic here - questions should ask for a component recommendation. However, there is a [raspberrypi.se] site on the Stack Exchange network; have a read of their [help center](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and see if they can help you.

Comment: @ArtOfCode not schematics exactly, i kind of needed help on what components to use for this sort of a project. Like Andy suggested there is stuff like mesh networks with ZigBee and stuff. But not sure which components to use exactly

Comment: @user282190 I'm afraid we can't help you with that - we're looking for you to identify what components you need by yourself, then ask for a recommendation of them. The Raspberry Pi site can't help either - I've just checked. Perhaps you might have some success asking this on [reddit's r/ElectronicCircuits](https://www.reddit.com/r/electronic_circuits/)?

Comment: Hi, if you're looking for some wireless *IoT*-thingies, check these out: [nodeMCU](http://nodemcu.com/index_en.html), [ParticleIO](http://www.particle.io). If you can be more specific you're also welcome at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/. Just make sure to have a search first to get your requirements sorted out. Shopping recommendations would be off-topic over there.